# Copy second row until last row with blanks in a column after filtering data

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I hope i can explain this well. I am having a difficulty in my code and what code should i use. 
I have a big data, that needs to be filter first. and the range is not consistent.

after filtering data, i have to copy the second row (this is not to copy the Column name), until the last row with blanks.

I tried this code, but it didn't work

```
Sheets("Big5").Select
Range("P1").Select

Dim testlrow As Long
testlrow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Dim rngBIGcode As Range
Set rngBIGcodeM = Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, ActiveCell.Column), Cells(Rows.Count, ActiveCell.Column))
    rngBIGcodeM.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown) & testlrow).Select
```

I have to copy the second row from P1, until the last row.

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code, starting with using `Select` and `ActiveCell`.  You also declare your range, then use a different name to `Set`.  One way to ensure your variables are properly declared is to type `Option Explicit` above your `Sub`. Then it will verify your variables.  Ensure that your objects are well-defined by using the worksheet variable in front of the cells.  This is how your code could work:

```
   Sub Test ()
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim testlrow As Long
        Dim rngBIGcodeM as Range

        Set ws = Sheets("Big5")
        testlrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row

        Set rngBIGcodeM = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, "P"), ws.Cells(testlrow, "P"))
        rngBIGcodeM.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy 'Enter Destination Here

        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! It Worked! :)